# Equality of two functions through Liouville's theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I would like to understand the proof of the following Lemma:

***Lemma.** Let $a_{1}, \dots, a_{M}$ and $b_{1}, \dots, b_{N}$, with $M \leq N$, be $M + N$ points in the complex plane such that $b_{n} \neq b_{l}$ if $n \neq l$. Then one has that*
\begin{equation}
\frac{\prod_{1 \leq m \leq M}(x - a_{m})}{\prod_{1 \leq n \leq N}(x - b_{n})} = \delta_{N, M} + \sum_{l = 1}^{N} \frac{\prod_{1 \leq m \leq M}(b_{l} - a_{m})}{(x - b_{l}) \prod_{1 \leq n \leq N, \hspace{0.5 mm} n \neq l}(b_{l} - b_{n})}
\end{equation}
*as a rational identity in $x$.*

The proof says that the result is immediate from Liouville's theorem, because the residues of the simple poles at $x = b_{n}$, $n = 1, ..., N$, and the asymptotics for $x \to \infty$ are equal on both sides of the equation. But this argument is not clear to me. How can I use Liouville's theorem? Is it possible to be more specific and detailed about this?

Comment: Can you please attach the (name of the) textbook/PDF/course notes that you're reading from and where this lemma is taken from? Thank you.

Comment: The PDF is https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=96f9ff60af228759664a28ad091cff12c4a28bfa on page 312

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume $M<N$ and denote the left-hand side of OPs identity with $f$, so that we have
\begin{align*}
f(z)=\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M\left(z-a_m\right)}{\prod_{n=1}^N\left(z-b_n\right)}
\end{align*}
Since the $b_q, 1\leq q\leq N$ are pairwise different, we have simple poles and can calculate the residue at $z=b_q$. We obtain
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Res}\left(f;b_q\right)&=\lim_{z\to b_q}(z-b_q)f(z)
=\lim_{z\to b_q}\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M\left(z-a_m\right)}{\prod_{{n=1}\atop{n\ne q}}^N\left(z-b_n\right)}\\
&=\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M\left(b_q-a_m\right)}{\prod_{{n=1}\atop{n\ne q}}^N\left(b_q-b_n\right)}
\end{align*}
If we subtract from $f$ the *principal part* of $f$ at $z=b_q$ we obtain with
\begin{align*}
f(z)-\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M\left(b_q-a_m\right)}{\left(z-b_q\right)\prod_{{n=1}\atop{n\ne q}}^N\left(b_q-b_n\right)}
\end{align*}
a function which has now a *removable* singularity at $z=b_q$. Let's do this for each of the simple poles.

We consider
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{g(z)=f(z)-\sum_{l=1}^N\frac{\prod_{m=1}^M\left(b_l-a_m\right)}{\left(z-b_l\right)\prod_{{n=1}\atop{n\ne l}}^N\left(b_q-b_n\right)}}
\end{align*}
which is an *entirce* function, since now all singularities $b_q,1\leq q\leq N$ are removable. This is the right setting for the *[Theorem of Liouville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))*.

> **Liouville**:
> We show the function $g\equiv 0$ thus proving OPs claim.
>
> - The function $g$ is a sum of rational functions with degree of polynomials at the numerator less than the degree of the polynomials of the denominator. This implies
>   \begin{align*}
>   \lim_{|z|\to\infty}|g(z)|=0\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
> - The function $g$ is entire, that is analytic in the whole complex plane so that it is continuous at $\mathbb{C}$ and therefore bounded at $|g(z)|<R$ with $R$ large.
>
> Combining these two aspects we see that $g$ is bounded in $\mathbb{C}$ thus $g$ is constant due to Liouville's theorem. From (1) it follows, that
> \begin{align*}
> g\equiv 0
> \end{align*}
> and the claim follows.

The case $M=N$ is left to the OP.

**Note:** Liouville's theorem also justifies the partial fractional decomposition in the more general case where not all poles are necessarily simple. See for instance *[this paper](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Erauch/555/partialfractions.pdf)*.