# Fraction decomposition, how to find coefficients?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

How to decompose? Can anybody give a hint
$\frac{1}{(x^n-1)^2}$.
$\frac{1}{(x^n-1)^2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}}{x-\zeta_{i}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{b_{i}}{(x-\zeta_{i})^2}$.
$1=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{a_{i}(x^n-1)^2}{x-\zeta_{i}}+\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{b_{i}(x^n-1)^2}{(x-\zeta_{i})^2}=f(x)$.
Then if $x=\zeta_{j}$
$1=f(\zeta_{j})=b_{j}(\zeta_{j}-\zeta_{k_{1}})^2(\zeta_{j}-\zeta_{k_{2}})^2...(\zeta_{j}-\zeta_{k_{n-1}})^2$, where $\zeta_{j}\neq \zeta_{k_{i}}$, so I can find $b_{j}$.
What about $a_{j}$?

Comment: Not sure if it's the best strategy, but you can decompose $g(x) = 1/(x^n-1)$ and then decompose every off-diagonal term in $(g(x))^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we use that the *partial fraction decomposition* of a rational function is given by the *sum of the [principal parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_part)* of the *[Laurent series expansions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_part)* at the poles. More precisely we have the following *[Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition#Residue_method)*:

**Partial Fractions Decomposition Theorem:** Suppose that $R(z)/D(z)$ is a rational function with degree of $R$ less than the degree of $D$. Denote by $r_j$ the distinct roots of the denominator $D$ and $m_j$ their multiplicities. Let $S_j(z)$ denote the principal part of the *Laurent expansion* of $R/D$ at the root $r_j$. The singular point $r_j$ is either removable or a pole of order $\leq m_j$ and
\begin{align*}
\frac{R(z)}{D(z)}=\sum_{j}S_j(z)
\end{align*}
See for instance *[this paper](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Erauch/555/partialfractions.pdf)*.

---

Denoting OPs function by $f_n$ we have
\begin{align*}
f_n(z)&=\frac{1}{\left(z^n-1\right)^2}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\qquad\qquad \zeta_k^n=1, 0\leq k\leq n-1
\end{align*}
where $\zeta_k$ are the $n$-th roots of unity, where $0\leq k\leq n-1$.

We show the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(z)}&\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{\left(z^n-1\right)^2}}\\
&\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}
-2\left(\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_l\right)}\right)\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}\right)}\tag{1}
\end{align*}

> We start with the calculation of the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}$ by calculating the residue of $f_n$ at $\zeta_q$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{Res}\left(f,\zeta_q\right)}&=\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\right)\\
> &=\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &=\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\left(\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_l\right)^2}\right)\right)
> \prod_{{k=0}\atop{{k\ne q}\atop{k\ne l}}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\tag{3}\\
> &=\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{-2}{\left(z-\zeta_l\right)^3}
> \prod_{{k=0}\atop{{k\ne q}\atop{k\ne l}}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{-2}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_l\right)}
> \prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}}\tag{4}\\
> \end{align*}
> which is the coefficient of $\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}$ in (1).

*Comment:*

- In (2) we cancel the factor $\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2$.
- In (3) we apply a generalized Leibniz product rule. Recall that for instance
  \begin{align*}
  \left(fgh\right)^{\prime}=f^{\prime}gh+fg^{\prime}h+fgh^{\prime}
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we merge $\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}$ into the product.

> We now obtain the coefficient of $\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}$ by calculating the residue of $(z-\zeta_q)f_n$ at $\zeta_q$. We get
> \begin{align*}
> f_q(z)&=f(z)\left(z-\zeta_q\right)=\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\\
> \color{blue}{\mathrm{Res}\left(f,\zeta_q\right)}&=\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\left(z-\zeta_q\right)f_q(z)
> =\lim_{z\to \zeta_q}\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_k\right)^2}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}}\tag{5}
> \end{align*}
> which is the coefficient of $\left(\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}\right)^2$ in (1).

We obtain from (5) and (4)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f_n(z)}&=\frac{1}{\left(z^n-1\right)^2}\\
&=\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}\\
&\qquad+\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{-2}{\left(z-\zeta_l\right)}
\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}\left(\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}
-2\left(\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_l\right)}\right)\frac{1}{z-\zeta_q}\right)}
\end{align*}
and the claim (1) follows.

**Example: $n=3$:**

Let's check (1) with a small value $n=3$. We consider
\begin{align*}
f_3(z)&=\frac{1}{\left(z^3-1\right)^2}
\end{align*}
with the poles
\begin{align*}
\zeta_0=1, \quad &\zeta_1=-\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\\
&\zeta_2=\overline{\zeta_1}=-\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
\end{align*}
We obtain according to (1)
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f_3(z)}&=\sum_{q=0}^{2}\left(\prod_{{k=0}\atop{k\ne q}}^2\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_k\right)^2}\right)
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)^2}-2\sum_{{l=0}\atop{l\ne q}}^2\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_q-\zeta_l\right)}\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_q\right)}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_0-\zeta_1\right)^2\left(\zeta_0-\zeta_2\right)^2}
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_0\right)^2}-2\left(\frac{1}{\zeta_0-\zeta_1}+\frac{1}{\zeta_0-\zeta_2}\right)\frac{1}{z-\zeta_0}\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_1-\zeta_0\right)^2\left(\zeta_1-\zeta_2\right)^2}
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_1\right)^2}-2\left(\frac{1}{\zeta_1-\zeta_0}+\frac{1}{\zeta_1-\zeta_2}\right)\frac{1}{z-\zeta_1}\right)\\
&\qquad+\frac{1}{\left(\zeta_2-\zeta_0\right)^2\left(\zeta_2-\zeta_1\right)^2}
\left(\frac{1}{\left(z-\zeta_2\right)^2}-2\left(\frac{1}{\zeta_2-\zeta_0}+\frac{1}{\zeta_2-\zeta_1}\right)\frac{1}{z-\zeta_2}\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{9}\left(\frac{1}{(z-1)^2}-\frac{2}{z-1}\right)}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{-\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{18}\left(\frac{1}{\left(z+\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)^2}
+\frac{1+i\sqrt{3}}{z+\left(\frac{1}{2}-i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right)}\\
&\qquad\color{blue}{-\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{18}\left(\frac{1}{\left(z+\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\right)^2}
+\frac{1-i\sqrt{3}}{z+\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}\right)}
\end{align*}
which was verified with the help of Wolfram Alpha.

**Note:** The validity of the *Partial Fractions Decomposition Theorem* is an immediate consequence of *[Liouvilles Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis))*.
A special case dealing with simple poles is considered *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803396/equality-of-two-functions-through-liouvilles-theorem/4803652#4803652)*.